# Abnormally high memory consumption MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Comrades. There is a problem. Short description: there is an application on NodeJS (cluster is used, sits on 2 protsah). There is MongoDB (replicated). The total value of all bases is ~ 5 gig. For the day of work, the monga exceeds the limit of 8GB and hangs. There are not many requests to the application, about 5000 per hour ... The question is how to limit the mongo and do it so that it does not fall.

Comment: Have you checked the number of connections? Often, that will consume your memory.

Comment: 226 connections

Comment: check to see if you are connecting with mongodb more that once. You should connect to database only once and that connection should have a pool of 100 connections.

Comment: Now mongodb have 50000++ free connections. And rigth, connecto to database once only

Comment: Is 8GB the actual memory usage (RSS), or the virtual memory _space_ (VSZ) that the process occupies?